# Type Error : Method.bind is not a function

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native. I try to create pie chart using 'react-native-pathjs-charts' library, but I got an error mentioning `method.bind is not a function`.

Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Animated, Easing, TouchableOpacity, Image, Linking} from 'react-native';
import { Bar } from 'react-native-pathjs-charts'
import { Pie } from 'react-native-pathjs-charts'

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {

};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = { 
      Default_Rating: 2,
      Max_Rating : 5,
    }
    this.Star = 'https://aboutreact.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/star_filled.png';
    this.Star_With_Border = 'https://aboutreact.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/star_corner.png';
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0)
    }

  UpdateRating( key )
  {
      this.setState({ Default_Rating: key });
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.animate()
  }

  animate(){
    this.animatedValue.setValue(0)
    Animated.timing(
      this.animatedValue,
      {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 2000,
        easing: Easing.linear
      }
    ).start(() => this.animate())
  }

  render() {
    let data = [{
      "name": "Washington",
      "population": 7694980
    }, {
      "name": "Oregon",
      "population": 2584160
    }, {
      "name": "Minnesota",
      "population": 6590667,
      "color": {'r':223,'g':154,'b':20}
    }, {
      "name": "Alaska",
      "population": 7284698
    }]

    let options = {
      margin: {
        top: 20,
        left: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 20
      },
      width: 350,
      height: 350,
      color: '#2980B9',
      r: 50,
      R: 150,
      legendPosition: 'topLeft',
      animate: {
        type: 'oneByOne',
        duration: 200,
        fillTransition: 3
      },
      label: {
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        fontSize: 8,
        fontWeight: true,
        color: '#ECF0F1'
      }
    }

    let React_Native_Rating_Bar = [];

    for( var i = 1; i <= this.state.Max_Rating; i++ )
        {
          React_Native_Rating_Bar.push(
                <TouchableOpacity 
                  activeOpacity = { 0.7 } 
                  key = { i } 
                  onPress = { this.UpdateRating.bind( this, i ) }>     
                    <Image 
                      style = { styles.StarImage } 
                      source = { ( i <= this.state.Default_Rating ) ? { uri: this.Star } : { uri: this.Star_With_Border } } />
                </TouchableOpacity>

          );
        }

    const marginLeft = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [0, 150]
    })

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Merchant Dashboard</Text>
      </View>
      <View style = { styles.childView }>
      {
        React_Native_Rating_Bar
      }
      </View>
      <Text style = { styles.textStyle1 }>
        Rating for your shop : 
        { this.state.Default_Rating } / { this.state.Max_Rating }
      </Text>
      <View style={styles.box}>
        <Animated.Text
          style={{
            marginLeft,
            color: 'green'}} > 
            Possitive Reviews!
        </Animated.Text>
        <Animated.Text
          style={{
            marginLeft,
            color: 'red'
          }}>
          Negative Reviews!
        </Animated.Text>
        <View style={styles.btnStyle}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.FacebookStyle} activeOpacity={0.5}>
          <Image
            source={{
              uri:
                'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/8/8816.png',
            }}
            style={styles.ImageIconStyle}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.FacebookStyle} activeOpacity={0.5}>
          <Image
            source={{
              uri:
                'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_play_circle_outline_48px-512.png',
            }}
            style={styles.ImageIconStyle}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.FacebookStyle} activeOpacity={0.5}>
          <Image
            source={{
              uri:
                'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/56/56616.png',
            }}
            style={styles.ImageIconStyle}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.container1}>
        <Pie data={data}
          options={options}
          accessorKey="population"
          margin={{top: 20, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20}}
          color="#2980B9"
          pallete={
            [
              {'r':25,'g':99,'b':201},
              {'r':24,'g':175,'b':35},
              {'r':190,'g':31,'b':69},
              {'r':100,'g':36,'b':199},
              {'r':214,'g':207,'b':32},
              {'r':198,'g':84,'b':45}
            ]
          }
          r={50}
          R={150}
          legendPosition="topLeft"
          label={{
            fontFamily: 'Arial',
            fontSize: 8,
            fontWeight: true,
            color: '#ECF0F1'
          }}
          />
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.LinkStyle} onPress={ ()=> Linking.openURL('https://google.com') } >Click Here To view Suggetions for improvement of the shop.</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  container1: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
  },
  childView:{
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  StarImage:{
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    resizeMode: 'cover'
  },
  textStyle1:
  {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#000',
    marginTop: 15
  },
  title:{
    fontSize: 23,
    color: '#000'  
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  box: {
    marginTop: 10,
    height:80,
    width: 300,
    backgroundColor: '#b2beb5',
  },
  btnStyle:{
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  btn2Style:{
    alignItems: 'flex-end'
  },
  ImageIconStyle: {
    padding: 10,
    margin: 5,
    height: 25,
    width: 25,
    resizeMode: 'stretch',
  },
  TextStyle: {
    color: '#fff',
    marginBottom: 4,
    marginRight: 20,
  },
  SeparatorLine: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    width: 1,
    height: 40,
  },
  LinkStyle: {
    color: '#E91E63',
    textDecorationLine: 'underline'
  },
});
```

Comment: Whatever you're calling bind on/from is not a function. So provide a proper error stack and share what debugging you've done

Answer (score 2):

In my case the error was due to react-native-d3multiline-chart which occured after upgrading react-native version from 0.54.6 to 0.59.1 because internally react-native-d3multiline-chart was using react-native-svg.
I solved this error by forking this repository and changing the react-native-svg version to 9.3.3 in package.json of react-native-d3multiline-chart.
Pointing to this updated commit id in my project package.json for react-native-d3multiline-chart solved this error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use arrow function. Like this,

```
onPress={() => this.UpdateRating.bind(this, i)}
```

If this not working, pls share your error log to understand error clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into this exact issue (after a RN upgrade, 0.57.8 -> 0.59.1) and am almost certain is it because the react-native-pathjs-charts library is no longer maintained, and is pointing at an old / wrong version of react-native-svg.

While I haven't solved it yet (will update), my suspicion is that updating react-native-svg & updating the package.json of react-native-pathjs-charts to not explicitly use v~5.5.1 will get us in the right direction.

UPDATE: I was able to fix it (temporarily, will need to fork the charts repo) by manually updating the module's package.json to point at my own local react-native-svg module:

```
"dependencies": {
  "lodash": "^4.12.0",
  "paths-js": "^0.4.5"
},
"peerDependencies": {
  "react-native-svg": "9.3.3"
},
```

Just make sure you're properly adding react-native-svg to your project.